# Cannot deactivate LV due to partition device

Tags: partition, lvm, device

I need to be able to deactivate an LV but cannot after partprobing it and finding gaining access to its partitions in /dev/mapper. It seems I need some way of 'un-partprobing' the disk, but I have no idea how and would welcome some advice.

Here's what's happening, in case I'm missing something else:

`lvchange -a y /dev/vg/mylv` activates the lv fine

`partprobe /dev/vg/mylv` results in lv partition being found and device creation at */dev/mapper/vg-mylvp1*

`lvchange -a n /dev/vg/mylv` now fails - *LV vg/mylv in use: not deactivating*

**Just to be clear** I've checked that this volume is not mounted using every method I know how (including those suggested here). I presume it is in use/being held somewhere, but I cannot determine where. It is only after running partprobe that I can no longer deactivate the LV. Is there any way to force the deactivation? Has anyone else come across this?

**26/7** - Still not managed to progress on from this issue. I did, however, come across [this](http://markmail.org/thread/glzj77nlpnqajyjm) forum post talking about an LV staying 'open' if mounted as a loop. Could this be what is happening here? Does `partprobe` read using a loop mount? How can I see a list of active loop devices?

Comment: Can not reproduce that problem. Doing a "lvchang -a n" works just fine even if partprobe has been run, there is a /dev/mapper/ entry etc. Are you sure there is no automatic mounting happening? Because the error message you get I exactly what I get after I've also mounted the logical volume.

Comment: Definitely does not seem to be mounted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The helpful folks at the #lvm channel on [Freenode](http://www.freenode.net/) found a solution for me! One simply needs to deactivate the partition mapping using the command `kpartx -d /dev/vg/mylv`

This removes the partition device entry and allows me to once against deactivate the LV without problems.

Answer (score -1):

Something has that lv mounted. Unmount it first, then deactivate it.

Comment: Well, I'm using LVMs as storage for Xen domains so partitioning them seems perfectly natural. I'll check once more for any mount points though.

Comment: Sorry about that. *I do the same thing* (under KVM). But why have the host mess with the partitions on the LV? I usually do everything I need from the VMs. Try using `fuser` to if it will tell you what has it mounted.

Comment: I'm trying to provision the initial template (os file system etc) in a partition before running each vm for the first time. And `fuser` reports nothing, checked both the partition device and the lv device in three locations - /dev/mapper/vg-mylv, /dev/dm-3 (as fdisk shows it to exist as) and /dev/vg/mylv.

Comment: Try using another VM for the provisioning. Has the benefit of testing the LV as a disk for a VM.

Comment: A device lock doesn't necessarily imply a mount.